# Fetch POST with some headers

Tags: javascript, soap, react-native, fetch

I want to POST some data using `fetch` function. I've been testing with `curl` command with the aim of find the correct response. Then I found that the command that works as I want looks like this:

```
curl -0 -A '' -X POST -H 'Accept: ' -H 'Content-type: text/xml;    charset="utf-8"' -H "SOAPACTION: \"urn:Belkin:service:basicevent:1#SetBinaryState\"" --data '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><s:Body><u:SetBinaryState xmlns:u="urn:Belkin:service:basicevent:1"><BinaryState>0</BinaryState></u:SetBinaryState></s:Body></s:Envelope>' -s http://192.168.1.48:49153/upnp/control/basicevent1
```

The parameters of `fetch`that I've setted:

```
fetch('http://192.168.1.48:49153/upnp/control/basicevent1', {
 method: 'POST', 
 headers: {
   'Accept' : '',
   'Content-type': text/xml; charset="utf-8",
   'SOAPACTION': "urn:Belkin:service:basicevent:1#SetBinaryState"
 },
 body: ('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><s:Body><u:SetBinaryState xmlns:u="urn:Belkin:service:basicevent:1"><BinaryState>0</BinaryState></u:SetBinaryState></s:Body></s:Envelope>')
})
```

I don't know if the problem is in the HTTP version or other headers settings but I receive an error response.

Comment: `text/xml; charset="utf-8"` should be wrapped in apostrophes.

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I modified the request. The problem was the content time and some fields within the body.

```
'Content-type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8',
```

Answer (score 1):

`fetch` api uses `promises` to handle callback results.

In your case:

```
     fetch('http://192.168.1.48:49153/upnp/control/basicevent1', {
     method: 'POST', 
     headers: {
       'Accept' : '',
       'Content-type': 'text/xml; charset="utf-8"',
       'SOAPACTION': "urn:Belkin:service:basicevent:1#SetBinaryState"
     },
     body: ('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><s:Body><u:SetBinaryState xmlns:u="urn:Belkin:service:basicevent:1"><BinaryState>0</BinaryState></u:SetBinaryState></s:Body></s:Envelope>')
     }).catch(function(err) {
       // Error :(
     });
```

Also, `content-type` should be `"application/json; charset=utf-8"`.

Comment: The error that I receive is an "invalid action" from UPnP. The thing is that I want to "translate" the curl command that I said into fecth function.

I told you that **curl command works as I want** with the parameters at the beginning of the question. So don't now why you say that `content-type` should be `"application/json; charset=utf-8"`.